# C# Learning to use Sql commands INSERT

Tags: c#, sql, database

Hi im trying to insert data into my DataBase. The program runs but it never save the values!!.

heres the code:

```
 using System.Data.SqlClient;

 namespace Database_1._0
 {
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"DataSource=LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Luis\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Database_1._0\Database_1._0\DB.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataReader dr;

    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
    string user = "1614258779876465426";
    string pass = "3Cp5CeXrfghdfght";
    string frecuencyCode = "ANNUAL";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cmd.Connection = cn;
    }

    private void logo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Database_1._0 \nWritten by: Luis", "About");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        cn.Open();
        using (SieteWS SieteWS = new SieteWS())
        {                
            Respuesta respuesta = SieteWS.SearchSeries(user, pass, frecuencyCode);
            foreach (internetSeriesInfo seriesInfo in respuesta.SeriesInfos)
            {

                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Serie] ([SerieID], [SerieName], [SerieFrecuency]) VALUES (@SerieID, @SerieName, @SerieFrecuency)";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SerieID", seriesInfo.seriesId);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SerieName", seriesInfo.spanishTitle);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SerieFrecuency", seriesInfo.frequency);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cn.Close();
            }
         }
     }
}
}
```

and the Error says: 
errorCS0103: The name 'CommandText' does not exist in the current context. And when I use a watch I found out this: cmd.CommandText =""; . Can somebody tell me what im doing wrong please.?

Comment: Which line of code shows that error?  That's a *compiler* error, which means that your statement of "The program runs" is entirely false.  Please clearly indicate the *actual error* and *actual behavior* of the code.

Comment: Also note that you are closing the connection _inside the loop_, so only one record would ever get updated.  Best to create connections and commands using `using` statements, closing them only when everything is complete.

Comment: The first time through your `foreach` loop your connection is closed.

Comment: @David Im sorry is in the cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Serie] ([SerieID], [SerieName], [SerieFrecuency]) VALUES (SerieID, SerieName, SerieFrecuency)"; part. I use a CheckPoint and add a watch there and i get this: errorCS0103: The name 'CommandText' does not exist in the current context. If dont do that the program just end "fine" but my table in the data base remain empty.

Comment: @LuisDanielAparicio: That error doesn't make sense for that line of code.  It seems *highly likely* that you're confusing something here.  Either that isn't the actual code, or that isn't the actual error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first of all. move `cn.Close();` outside of the loops. If it's not the cause for your problem now, it will cause a problem later.

If that doesn't fix your problem look further.

It's just a poke in the dark given the information I have, but try  running following code sets (inside foreach loop) and see if any of them work:

**set 1:**

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [dbo].[Serie] ([SerieID], [SerieName], [SerieFrecuency]) 
 VALUES ('"+seriesInfo.seriesId+"', '"+seriesInfo.spanishTitle+"'
         , '"+seriesInfo.frequency+"')", cn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

**set 2:**

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [dbo].[Serie] ([SerieID], [SerieName], [SerieFrecuency]) 
 VALUES (@SerieID, @SerieName, @SerieFrecuency)", cn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SerieID", seriesInfo.seriesId);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SerieName", seriesInfo.spanishTitle);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SerieFrecuency", seriesInfo.frequency);
```

Let me know how it works out

Comment: Set 2 works fine :D .Thank you for the 'cn.Close()' suggestion btw. And thank you again!!.

Answer (score -2):

Try this...

Modify the line below to include the name of the database. So that it will read [Your database Name].[dbo].[Serie]

cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Serie] ([SerieID], [SerieName], [SerieFrecuency]) VALUES (@SerieID, @SerieName, @SerieFrecuency)";

Your default database may not be the one that has your "Serie" table in it.

Comment: u.u nop. The table remain empty :/